# Analyses of continuous variable like time to event within clinical setting

Tags: survival, continuous-data, clinical-trials, kaplan-meier

My apologies if this has been previously answered.

I am fairly new to statistics of clinical trials and I want to know how the expert statisticians handle continuous variables like "time to event" to identify responder groups and non responder groups within a clinical trial.

I am assuming Survival graphs (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survminer/vignettes/Informative_Survival_Plots.html#motivation) could be one but I may be wrong.

Kindly provide insights and guidance.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y. Lin, in [Contemp Clin Trials Commun. 2016 Apr 14;3:65-69](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.conctc.2016.04.001), nicely summarizes the definition and problems of "responder analysis" at the beginning of the Discussion:

> A responder analysis is one in which each subject is classified as either a “responder” or a “non-responder”, and the proportions of patients who benefit are quantified and compared between treatment groups... It has been widely acknowledged that the main concern about the responder analysis is the arbitrary nature of the definition of a response. A second problem with the analysis is the dramatic reduction in statistical power by dichotomizing
> continuous endpoints.

With a continuous outcome, that means setting an arbitrary cutoff to distinguish "responders" from "non-responders." The problems this can lead to in practice are outlined in [this web post](https://s4be.cochrane.org/blog/2019/07/08/responder-analysis-identifying-responders-in-clinical-trials/).

With time-to-event data, one typically sees reports of relative hazards with and without the new treatment, based on an assumption of a shared baseline risk of the event, rather than "responder analysis." Such formal survival analysis has the advantage of using information even from individuals who haven't passed beyond an arbitrary threshold for "response" like "3-year survival." You might see reports of estimated 3-year survival by treatment group, but that's not "responder analysis" as the phrase is typically used.

In [immunotherapy for cancer](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-85696-3), however:

> Many studies have shown that the shape of the survival curve for immunotherapy is different than for chemotherapy, with some extra early deaths with immunotherapy and a plateau of long survivors later on.

In that case a comparison of outcomes of immunotherapy versus chemotherapy would involve interpreting the different shapes of survival curves, as you suggest. The focus is then on identifying factors associated with being in the "plateau of long survivors" or the group with "extra early deaths."